# Copy multiple sheets by filtering value and paste without formula to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Now I'm facing one issue. I have one excel workbook which have 5 sheets (sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,summary and summary2)

I want to make a new workbook which include 5 sheets.
but for sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3, I want to filter by region.
for summary and summary2, I wanna keep as original.

In sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3, there is one column which is Region and all are 8 regions.

so the final workbooks will be 8 and all 5 sheets need to included. then want to save with region name for all files.

I tried with the following code, but it only copy for one sheet

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub export_file()
Dim tB As Excel.Workbook
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ExportArray As Variant
Dim ShName As Variant
Dim ExportName As String

Dim varResult As Variant

Set tB = ThisWorkbook
ExportArray = Array("TSM_Wise ", "CSE_Wise ", "QR_Wise ")

For Each ShName In ExportArray
    Debug.Print ShName
    tB.Sheets(ShName).Copy
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
        ExportName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(tB.Path & "\Textstring123", "Excel Files *.xls", , "Save " & ShName)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            ExportName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(tB.Path & "\Textstring123", , , "Save " & ShName)
        Else
            'No error, everything went well with filters
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'String 8 and Boolean 11
    If VarType(ExportName) <> 8 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=ExportName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
    End If
    DoEvents
    wb.Close
Next ShName
    
End Sub
```

Comment: How does the Region column looks like on Sheet1-Sheet3? Pls. show a sample of it.

Comment: It seems your string array only has 3 sheets? Also I would refrain from using ActiveWorkbook and ThisWorkbook, instead refer to them by name. I think it could be that once you paste the first sheet, the active/This workbooks change